# How to include third party licenses in an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have an ASP.NET application which use a bunch of thrid party libraries like YUI, NLog etc.

I want to include the license(readme) txt files of all these third party libraries with my application.

I want to know if there is a standard way of doing this, or how do other people(you) do this in their project.

Any help and suggestions will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I keep the license files with the `.dlls` and other files they go with.

Since I don't like to commit the `/bin` folder (which is where the third-party `.dlls` normally end up), I save them in a `dependencies` folder that gets copied to `/bin` during the build process.